# Laravel eloquent in Lumen api dont save when data comes from HTTP Client Laravel, but when i test with Postman that works

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen, guzzle

I have a page with send data to an Lumen API. I send the data using the Laravel Http Client, like this:

```
    $url = env('API_ADDRESS');
    $data= [
        'p1' => $request->input('p1'),
        'p2' => $request->input('p2')
    ];
    $headers = [
        'key' => env('API_KEY')
    ];
    $req = Http::withHeaders($headers)->post($url, $data);
```

The status code from this request is 200.

In my API, i have a code like to receive the data and save it:

```
    public function SaveReq(Request $request)
{
    $data = [
        'status'=> 'success',
        'msg'=> ''
    ];

    try {
        $req = new Requisition();
        $req->p1 = $request->input('p1');
        $req->p2 = $request->input('p2');
        $req->save();

    } catch (ErrorException  $e) {
        $data['status'] = 'error';
        $data['msg'] = $e->getMessage();

    } finally {
        return json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

In my application that send the request, i can see the json of the api returns, but the api dont save the data, but if i send a request with this same data using Postman, my api save the data.

What am i doing wrong in the application that sends the data?

Answer (score -1):

1. check http method in your application and postman be same
2. before save data , use `dd($request->all());` to sure data
   send correctly